# Is there a way to check if a time-series is seasonal without manual inspection of its decomposition?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

While using various models to generate a forecast of a time-series it is needed to know if a time-series is seasonal or not.

I have searched about this topic but could only find people mentioning visual inspection of the seasonal decomposition of a time series to determine if the series is seasonal or not, but that becomes non viable when trying to generate forecasts for a large amount of items.

Is there a way to find out if a time series is seasonal?

Examples of when its needed to know if a time series is seasonal or not:

````py
# Auto Regression
model = statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AutoReg(demands, lags=3, seasonal=???)
fittedModel = model.fit()

# Holt-Winters
model = sm.tsa.ExponentialSmoothing(demands, trend='mul', seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=???)
fittedModel = model.fit()
```
````

Answer (score 2):

To do this in an automated way, what you could do is fit the most general model forms that include the ability to model seasonality (SARIMAX and ETS models specifically, which generalize both the AR and Holt Winters models that you fit), and find the best configurations for these models based on a criterion like AIC.

For example, for the SARIMA(P, D, Q, p, d, q) model, try a bunch of different models (grid search here should be fine) in terms of P, D, Q, p, d, q and pick the model that has the lowest AIC. If p, d, q are all 0, then you have evidence that suggests that there is very little (or no) seasonality in the data to warrent modeling it. Similar methods can be used for ETS(trend, seasonality) models. If the model with the lowest AIC has no seasonal state space transition equation, then similar logic can be applied.

This logic is exactly what auto.arima() and ets() does in R. Python likely has convenience wrappers to do this for you, but it's not hard to code this logic yourself.

Answer (score 2):

*without* methods of [time-series decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70403925/10452700)
(ie. Seasonal-Trend decomposition ) and Visual inspection of plots:

1. [*Autocorrelation Function (ACF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) or [*Partial Autocorrelation Function (PACF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_autocorrelation_function).

   - (Large) spikes at specific lags *could* indicate **seasonality**.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
```

---

[image: img]
2. Another statistical method is the [Ljung-Box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test).

- The Ljung-Box test is a test for the [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) ($H_0$) that the residuals of a time series are independently distributed. If the test indicates a lack of independence, it suggests that there might be some structure or **seasonality** in the residuals.

```py
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import acorr_ljungbox
```

Please note that these methods are not 100% proof, and the choice of method depends on the *characteristics* of *your* time series data. *Visual inspection of plots* and *domain knowledge* should still be considered to validate and interpret the results.

---

Full-code to reproduce:

````py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import acorr_ljungbox

# Generate a seasonal time series
np.random.seed(42)
timesteps = 100
seasonal_period = 10

time = np.arange(timesteps)
seasonal_component = np.sin(2 * np.pi * time / seasonal_period)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=timesteps)
time_series = seasonal_component + noise

# Plot the generated time series with added seasonality
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(time, time_series, label='Generated Time Series with Seasonality')
plt.plot(time, seasonal_component, label='Seasonality Component', linestyle='--', color='red', alpha=0.7)
plt.title('Generated Time Series with Seasonality')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# ACF and PACF analysis
lag_acf = acf(time_series, nlags=20)
lag_pacf = pacf(time_series, nlags=20)

# Ljung-Box test
lb_test_stat, lb_p_value = acorr_ljungbox(time_series, lags=20)

# Chosen significance level
significance_level = 0.05

# Plot ACF and PACF
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# ACF plot
plt.subplot(121)
plt.stem(lag_acf)
plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.title('Autocorrelation Function (ACF)')

# PACF plot
plt.subplot(122)
plt.stem(lag_pacf)
plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='gray')
plt.title('Partial Autocorrelation Function (PACF)')

plt.show()

# Print Ljung-Box test results
print("Ljung-Box Test Statistic:", lb_test_stat[0])
print("P-value:", lb_p_value[0])
print("Chosen Significance Level:", significance_level)

```
````